# Updating managed objects in a background thread and displaying them in main thread, what's wrong

Tags: iphone, core-data

Good evening,

I have some problem with CoreData and Concurrency, so I tried the simplest code and it still does not work. Could you indicate me where I am wrong.

I created a "DataManager" which update one CoreData object

```
@implementation OBSDataManager

@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (OBSDataManager *)initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator:(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)aPersistentStoreCoordinator {
   if (self = [super init]) {
      self.persistentStoreCoordinator = aPersistentStoreCoordinator;
   }

   return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
   [persistentStoreCoordinator release];

   [super dealloc];
}

- (void)start {

   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateData) withObject:nil];
}

- (void)updateData {
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
   context.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;

   // get chunk if it exists, or create it
   OBSChunk *chunk = [OBSChunk theChunkInContext:context];
   if (!chunk) {
      chunk = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Chunk"
                                            inManagedObjectContext:context];
   }

   while (1) {
      // update content
      chunk.text = [[NSDate date] description];

      // save it
      NSError *error;
      if ([context save:&error]) {
         NSLog(@"Problem on save");
      }
   }
   [context release];

}

@end
```

I have a view controller which displays content of my CoreData object

```
    @implementation MainViewController

@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize label;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIViewController
 // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(onCoreDataUpdate:)
                                                name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                              object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
   [super viewDidUnload];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                   name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                 object:nil];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark private
- (void)onCoreDataUpdate:(NSNotification *)updateNotification {
   [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:updateNotification];

   OBSChunk *chunk = [OBSChunk theChunkInContext:self.managedObjectContext];

   self.label.text = chunk.text;
}

@end
```

It appears that the chunk object that is fetch in onCoreDataUpdate method has faulted data.

Where am I wrong ?

Regards,
Quentin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-onCoreDataUpdate:` is being called on the background thread. Notifications are received on the thread they're sent from. You need to call back to the main thread to actually handle the update. You can use something like the following to handle this:

```
- (void)onCoreDataUpdate:(NSNotification *)updateNotification {
    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:_cmd withObject:updateNotification waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }
    [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:updateNotification];

    OBSChunk *chunk = [OBSChunk theChunkInContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    self.label.text = chunk.text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,
it works (application does not crash any more), but when I print object in debugger, data still appear as "fault". :(

Comment: What's wrong with the object being a fault? Objects don't have their underlying data faulted in until that data is accessed. Faults are a normal part of operation with CoreData.

Comment: Ok, it is just that the term "fault" is impressive. :p